# Javascript Private Property Performance on V8

Tags: javascript, performance, v8, private-members

I have created some tests on jsperf.app and the results are not in line with the charts in this V8 blog post: https://v8.dev/blog/faster-class-features

According to the "interpreted" chart in that link, on Chromium-based browsers, public class fields now initialize at the same speed as a "named property" and private class fields initialize less than 20% slower.  [Based on this test](https://jsperf.app/ceyosu/2), on Chrome 115, the latest release, on Windows 10/64, I am seeing both private and public class fields initializing 45% slower (+/-3%) than a property defined and initialized in a class constructor. On Android with the same version of Chrome it's the same, but with a wider +/- range. The private field is always a few percentage points slower than the public one.

[This version of the same test](https://jsperf.app/ceyosu/3) initializes 10 of each type of property, and private/public fields are close to 100% slower, so it has a cumulative effect, as you might expect.

What's the story here? I thought that V8 v10.0 was released into Chrome over a year ago.

Comment: _I don't have as specific a question_ unfortunately by definition that means this is the wrong place to post this, as interesting a discussion topic as it might be

Comment: @Clive So I should remove that part of the question?  I do have a specific question about V8.  Sorry I just read the notice at the top here.  Never mind.

Comment: If the preamble is useful to set the scene for the V8 question, then probably keep it, maybe just trim anything tangential or irrelevant. Ending the post with a specific question is always good, and a tl;dr wouldn’t hurt if you plan to keep most of the other info

Comment: @Clive But I should resubmit the question, not edit this one, right?  Excuse my ignorance, but I have not posted many questions here.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Difficult to say for sure, but if you plan to keep most of the text that’s in there at the moment I’d lean towards editing this one rather than reposting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the story here?

That V8 blog post isn't talking about the speed of `eval("class C { pub; }")` (which is essentially what your benchmark is measuring); instead it's talking about the performance of `new C();`. The assumption is that class definitions are rare (you don't really have millions of class declarations, do you?), whereas class instantiations are frequent and performance-critical (your app may well create millions of objects over the course of a run).

As you can see in [this updated version of your test](https://jsperf.app/ceyosu/4), field initialization performance is indeed pretty much identical in all three cases.

> I thought that V8 v10.0 was released into Chrome over a year ago.

Correct, V8 10.0 shipped in Chrome 100.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was misunderstanding what the blog post meant by "initialization".  Your updated version of the test aligns with my other tests around private vs public vs "named" property performance on Chrome: the same within <1%.  Firefox is another matter, with all kinds of different variations...